# OSX-Parse - How to get images in background

Tags: macos, thread-safety, parse-platform

I have this code going to get Parse images into my **OSX** app.

```
// give our representation to the image browser
- (id)imageRepresentation {
     NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    return [_file getData];
}
```

This works but results in :

```
Warning: A long-running Parse operation is being executed on the main thread. 
 Break on warnParseOperationOnMainThread() to debug.
```

I need to move the `[_file getData]` method to a background thread, and could use some help.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are getting -

`Warning: A long-running Parse operation is being executed on the main thread. 
 Break on warnParseOperationOnMainThread() to debug.`

Is simply a warning when running queries that are asynchronous. More information can be found [here](https://www.parse.com/questions/warnparseoperationonmainthread).

If you want to run a query in the background, use the `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:` method of the `PFQuery` class.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I am having a problem figuring the syntax  for running in the background, when used with the IKImageBrowser data source - an equivalent for [_file getData].

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean - if you've already retrieved an object, calling `getData` on it should not run another query. I suggest taking a look at the query documentation here: https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries/iOS